# R: plotting untransformed data on a log x axis (similar to plotting on log graph paper)

Tags: r, plot, logarithm

I have 3 sets of data that I am trying to plot on a single plot. The first data set x values range from ~ 1 to 1700 whereas the other two data sets x values are less than 20. Therefore I want to plot them on a log axis to show variations in all the data sets. However I do not want to transform the data as I want to be able to read the values off the graph. The x axis labels I would like are 1, 10, 100 and 1000 all equally spaced. Does anyone know how to do this? I can only find examples where the data is log as well as the axis. I have attached the code I am currently using below:
Thanks in advance for any help given.
Holly

```
Stats_nineteen<-read.csv('C:/Users/Holly/Documents/Software Manuals/R Stuff/Stats_nineteen.csv')
attach(Stats_nineteen)
x<-Max
x1<-Min
x2<-Max
y1<-Depth
y2<-Depth
par(bg="white")
par(xlog=TRUE)
plot(x2,y1, type="n", ylim=c(555,0), log="x", axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE)
box()
axis(3, at=c(1,10,100,1000), label=c(1,10,100,1000), pos=0, cex.axis=0.6)
axis(1, at=c(1,10,100,1000), label=c(1,10,100,1000), cex.axis=0.6)
axis(2, at=c(600,550,500,450,400,350,300,250,200,150,100,50,0), label=c
(600,"",500,"",400,"",300,"",200,"",100,"",0), cex.axis=0.6)
mtext("CLAST SIZE / mm", side=3, line=1, cex=0.6, las=0, col="black")
mtext("DEPTH / m", side=2, line=2, cex=0.6, las=0, col="black")
grid(nx = NULL, ny = NULL, col = "lightgray", lty = "solid",
lwd = par("lwd"), equilogs = TRUE)
par(new=TRUE)
lines(x1,y1, col="black", lty="solid", lwd=1)
lines(x2,y2, col="black", lty="solid", lwd=1)
polygon(c(x1,rev(x2)), c(y1,rev(y2)), col="grey", border="black")
par(new=TRUE)
plot(x=Average,y=Depth, type="o",
bg="red", cex=0.5, pch=21,
col="red", lty="solid",
axes=FALSE, xlim=c(0,1670), ylim=c(555,0),
ylab = "",xlab = "")
par(new=TRUE)
plot(x=Mode,y=Depth, type="o",
bg="blue", cex=0.5, pch=21,
col="blue", lty="solid",
axes=FALSE, xlim=c(0,1670), ylim=c(555,0),
ylab = "",xlab = "")
```

Comment: Edit your question to include str(Stats_nineteen).    With base graphics, if you want both the x and y axes to be log-transformed (which is what your axis calls appear to expect, you need to use log="xy" rather than your current specification. (You do not need to use par(new=TRUE) before calls to the lines function.) You'll need to set xlim and ylim to the full range of all values in the first call to `plot()`.

Comment: And as Chris said... don't use attach.

Comment: No it is just the x axis that I want to be a log - I have just copied the x axis onto side 3 as well. Ah ok, I didn't know if the lines would be considered as a new plotting function separate to the first plot so I popped it in there just in case. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in ggplot using `scale_x_log`

so something like:

```
myplot <- ggplot( StatsNinetee, 
                  aes (x = myResponse,
                       y = myPredictor,
                       groups = myGroupingVariable) ) +
          geom_point() +
          scale_x_log()
myplot
```

also, avoid `attach()` it can give odd behavior.

Comment: I'm fairly new to R so I haven't used the ggplot package yet. I will have a look through it and let you know how I get on, or if I undoubtedly have any subsequent issues - thank you!

Comment: @HollyElliott you would be well served to learn `ggplot2` as early as possible.